# PHP media streaming on Android

Tags: php, android, html, stream

The idea is to stream a video through PHP.

I created a PHP script and uploaded it to my free website. Then I embedded the video with the source path where I pass the values to it.

When I try it on my PC's browser it works fine. But when I try it on a WebView on Android it wont even show up.

Any help?

**streamer.php**

```
<?php
$file = './' . $_GET["file"];

$pos = (isset($_GET["pos"])) ? intval($_GET["pos"]): 0;

header("Content-Type: video/x-flv"); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

if($pos > 0) {
    print("FLV"); 
    print(pack('C',1));
    print(pack('C',1));
    print(pack('N',9));
    print(pack('N',9));
}

$fh = fopen($file,"rb");
fseek($fh, $pos);
fpassthru($fh);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

**Embed code**

```
<embed src="http://mywebsite.com/streamer.php?file=video.flv" />
```

**Tried also in HTML5 and in another video format**

```
<video id="vid">
   <source src="http://chris-mmt.site40.net/streamer.php?file=video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the `HTML5` method and thanks to this answer I got it working just fine:)

[WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video/3882736#3882736)