# Video is black, audio is fine with HTML5 video

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

I've got a WebView with an embedded HTML5  element.  PluginState is set to ON, JavaScript is enabled.  When the video should play, the audio stream plays, but the video is a black square on anything older than KitKat.  Everything's perfect on KitKat and up.  Any ideas?

Things I've tried:

1) Setting layer type to hardware/software
2) Using @JavascriptInterface to try to autoplay (due to pre-KK requiring user input for MediaElements)
3) Various encodings (H.264, WebM)

Comment: What is your video format?

Comment: See if this question helps you out in any way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video

Comment: any output from Logcat?

Answer (score 1):

If a parent view in the hierarchy has a software layer type, and its child has a hardware layer type, the child's mode is software, not hardware.  A prerequisite for WebView media playback is being in hardware layer mode.