# How to integrate HTML5 video player with seek, pause,play option in android code?

Tags: android

My requirement is to stream video using HTML5 player in android.
I referred this link to stream the -> [WebView and HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video.) 
.

It's streaming properly but there is no option to play, pause and seek the video position.

Comment: Check this example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_controls

Comment: can you share your code with xml as well