# Problem when load html5 videos into webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview, html5-video

I have a problem when load html5 into webview.
My app in first build play video success but when i clear/kill app open again, webview not play video when click play.

- Html5

```
<video src="url.mp4" controls poster="thumbnail.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;"><a href="url.mp4">Download video</a></video>
```

- Source load webview

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

String html = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='file:///android_asset/css/style.css'></head><body>"
+ htmlElement.getContent()
+ "</body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, mimetype, encoding, "");
```

I research and try fix this issue but not success
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video`
`https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36935939` v.v..

Anyone has the same my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share web page url so that i can check the issue and reply u again

Comment: Hi @AnkitGupta, my url [link](https://hls.mediacdn.vn/afamily/2019/4/5/naxd-155441642541219650669-bbbb1.mp4). Tks U!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

1. DashBoardFragment2.java :- 
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UREa7uGrQYcF-ABzPktBSjUcOPtytxSC/view?usp=sharing
2. dashboard.xml :-
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LlgbdSe-9bgUU5lsGZUGOX3Tg7bnVpzH/view?usp=sharing